# Unable to select values from Data Explorer results (firefox bug only)

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, firefox

After the recent release of the new Data Explorer code drop, I believe it's become impossible, to copy/paste values from the results.

This has been confirmed to fail on multipe user's Firefox browsers, but is confirmed to work on Chrome.

For example, I recently created [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/268584/distinct-stack-wide-accounts), which produces the single result:

[image: Result of query]

I cannot select that value to copy/paste it.

- Double-clicking the value briefly selects it, but then the selection immediately clears.
- Selecting the value with a mouse only works as the down-clicked mouse is dragged across the value, but as soon as you release the mouse button, the selection clears.

Comment: mmm, looks like a SlickGrid bug. Will fork and patch in a bit and then update SEDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone had already done the hard work of patching SlickGrid, so I forked the project and applied their changes (as the SlickGrid maintainer isn't able to work on the project right now), and then included the resulting file in Data Explorer.

[Fixed now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/61), pending a pull and redeploy. The result of pasting text copied across cells seems to be inconsistent between browsers (IE, Chrome, and Firefox all behave differently), but at least you can now actually copy it regardless of your browser.